# How can I backup my system to an USB stick?

Tags: backup

I would like to backup my disk, I'm using only 24GB, but the full partition size 255GB. I would like to backup the whole system to an 32GB Flash Drive, just in case if the system it's not working, I still can boot from the USB Stick, How can I do that? In this case is `dd` a good option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SBackup is a simple backup solution intended for desktop use. It can
>   backup any subset of files and directories. Exclusions can be defined
>   by regular expressions. A maximum individual file size limit can be
>   defined. Backups may be saved to any local and remote directories that
>   are supported by gnome-vfs. There is a Gnome GUI interface for
>   configuration and restore.<sup>1</sup>

To install it Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install sbackup
```

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Debian Admin](http://www.debianadmin.com/backup-and-restore-your-ubuntu-system-using-sbackup.html)</sup>

Based on the new information that you supplied, you can use Remastersys.  Remastersys will backup your install to ISO.  Then you can use the outcome to make a Live CD/USB which can be used to install the backup to disk.

Or you can use dd to clone the original disk to USB stick but you need a big enough USB drive so the backup will fit.

Another option is to use Clonezilla.  Clonezilla is an Open Source Software for Disk Imaging and Cloning, similar to ghost.  You can get it by [Clicking Here](http://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: I would like to create a bootable mirror from my systrm

Comment: 'Unable to locate packaage sbackup' as of 2022.